# Angularjs - showing element based on a presence of id in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyoen know how to check (in the View) for a presence of id in a given array?

Lets say I have an array like so:

```
var arr = [123, 456, 789];
```

and a data source like this:

```
var data = [
  {id: 123, name: 'foo'},
  {id: 456, name: 'bar'},
  {id: 789, name: 'baz'}
];
```

Now in the view while iterating over the `data` array I would like to show/hide elements based on a presence of `id` in the `arr` like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <span ng-show="item.id in arr"></span>
</div>
```

The above code `item.i in arr` of course does not work for obvious reasons. Anyone know how to achieve that functionality? Not to mention the ng-show block should always kick-in whenever the `arr` array is altered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a method in your scope

```
function MyCtrl( $scope ) {
  $scope.data = ...

  $scope.enabled = ...


  $scope.visible = function (id ) { 
    return $scope.enabled.indexOf(id) > -1
  } 

}
```

and

```
<span ng-show="visible(item.id)" ></span>
```